# How to trigger lambda once Cloudformation stack is created

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch-events

I have to trigger a lambda function once specific stack is created.

I have created the below CloudWatch event rule and associated the target to that lambda function but it is not triggering the lambda.

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.cloudformation"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "cloudformation.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "CreateStack"
    ],
    "stackName": [
      "sql-automate-04-08"
    ]
  }
}
```

Please let me know if i am missing anything here.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn’t work using CloudWatch Event Rules because the CloudFormation stack’s lifecycle events don’t reflect individual API calls.

However, you can configure CloudFormation to send stack events to an Amazon SNS topic via its [`NotificationARNs`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html#cfn-cloudformation-stack-notificationarns) property. An AWS Lambda function subscribed to that topic can then filter and process the events.

Comment: Yeah, i used that approach also but then i can see on my stack creation lambda is getting triggered multiple times. I have also set the Retry attemps to 0 but still it is triggering the lambda multiple times.

Comment: Yes, it’s triggered by each event, not only when the stack creation is complete. To address this you can apply an SNS filter policy: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-filtering.html

Comment: I have used the below subscription policy but now it is not triggering the lambda. {
  "ResourceStatus": [
    "CREATE_COMPLETE"
  ]
}

Answer (score 0):

This EventBridge Rule has worked for me:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.cloudformation"],
  "detail-type": ["CloudFormation Stack Status Change"],
  "region": ["us-east-1"],
  "detail": {
    "status-details": {
      "status": ["CREATE_COMPLETE"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke a lambda via custom resource which will trigger the lambda when stack creation is complete.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).